# Check Service status on multiple servers

Tags: powershell

I need to have a script which can check specific service status of multiple servers with credential. The main issue i am facing is the service list for each server is different. For example in one server it is webservice and in the other Database service etc. I  would like to keep a csv file with server name in the first column and its relevant services on the other. Script need to validate this and run so on.Also the output expecting is in CSV. Till now i did this much, stuck beyond.. hope somebody can help me on this.

```
$CSVData = import-csv ".\Service.csv"
$Servernames = $CSVData.Servername | sort -unique

$Cred = Get-Credential

foreach ($server in $Servernames) {

$Services = $CSVData | Where {$_.Servername -eq $Server} | Select service
foreach ($Service in $Services) {
    write-host $Server
    $Serv = $Service.service
    Get-WMIObject -computer $server -credential $cred -Query "Select * From Win32_Service WHERE Name Like '$Serv'" | select Name, state
}

}
```

Any suggestions? Also help to format the output to csv

Answer (score 1):

```
$CSVData = import-csv ".\Service.csv"
$Servernames = $CSVData.Servername | sort -unique
$output = @()

$Cred = Get-Credential

foreach ($server in $Servernames) {

$Services = $CSVData | Where {$_.Servername -eq $Server} | Select service
foreach ($Service in $Services) {
    write-host $Server
    $Serv = $Service.service
    #$ServStat = Get-WMIObject -computer $server -credential $cred -Query "Select * From Win32_Service WHERE Name Like '$Serv'" | select displayname, state
    $ServStat = Get-WMIObject -Query "Select * From Win32_Service WHERE Name Like '$Serv'" | select displayname, state
    $Info =New-object -Typename PSObject
    $Info | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Hostname" -value $Server
    $Info | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ServiceName" -value $ServStat.DisplayName
    $Info | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ServiceStatus" -value $ServStat.state
    $Output +=$Info
}
}

$Output | export-csv ".\Result.csv" -notype
```

This is the solution i found, suggest if there is room to improve

Answer (score 0):

Multiple ways of doing this.

You could start with a `machines.csv` file containing your server names and services:

```
server,service
server1,WinRM
server2,WinRM
...
```

Then you could import this CSV file with [`Import-CSV`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7):

```
$computers = Import-Csv -Path .\machines.csv
```

And then check the service status by running [`Get-Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-service?view=powershell-7) on the remote machines with [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7):

```
foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    $cred = Get-Credential -Message "Enter username and password for $($computer.Server)"
    Write-host "$($computer.Service) Service checking on $($computer.Server)" -b "green" -foregroundcolor "red"

    $serviceParams = @{
        "ComputerName" = $computer.Server
        "Command" = {Get-Service -Name $using:computer.Service}
        "Credential" = $cred
    }

    $service = Invoke-Command @serviceParams

    Write-Host "$($computer.Service) Service on $($computer.Server) : $($service.Status)" -b "green" -foregroundcolor "red"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment, unfortunately invoke command wont work in our environment, its blocked. i just did an edit to the older script and made some improvements . but still on the half way.

Comment: @rpr What about when you do it through WMI: `$service = Get-WMIObject Win32_Service -computer $computer.Server -credential $cred`?

Comment: Just did some research and came to solution like below , Any Suggestions ? 
$CSVData = import-csv ".\Service.csv"
$Servernames = $CSVData.Servername | sort -unique
$output = @()

$Cred = Get-Credential
$CSVData = import-csv ".\Service.csv"
$Servernames = $CSVData.Servername | sort -unique
$output = @()

$Cred = Get-Credential

foreach ($server in $Servernames) {

$Services = $CSVData | Where {$_.Servername -eq $Server} | Select service
 foreach ($Service in $Services) {
  write-host $Server
  $Serv = $Service.service